# emacsclient -c new frame cannot have an individual new sr-speedbar

Tags: frames, emacsclient, speedbar

Since emacsclient depends on emacs server, when I first start emacs server and then try:

```
emacsclient -c -n -a emacs --eval "(sr-speedbar-open)"
```

It reports that sr-speedbar is arlready opened. Is it possible to have individual sr-speedbar for every emacsclient -c new frame?

Right now the best I can do is to first close sr-speedbar then reopen it in a new frame.

```
emacsclient -c -n -e "(progn (sr-speedbar-close) (sr-speedbar-open))"
```

But sr-speedbar will be closed in all the other frames.